# Concatenate two grep outputs and display result in sequence

Tags: unix, grep, concatenation

I have to grep  word "random" from file A.log and also words "fail|pass" from same file.
But here, I want random to be searched including its previous line .

---

Let the contents of file be

The list is complete

random items     are

subject1

subject2

subject3

count begins here

failure detected

subject1

subject2

subject3

count ends here

item passed

subject1

subject2

subject3

---

If i use **egrep -B1 "random|fail|pass" A.log** .

Result is as follows.

```
 The list is complete

 random items are ...

 count begins here

 failure detected

 count ends here

  item passed
```

The resultant output will concatenate previous line for fail and pass as well.But 
 here i only need previous line  for pattern "random" and not for "fail|pass"

Result i am expecting.

```
The list is complete

   random items are ...      

   failure detected   

   item passed
```

Comment: So you mean you would like us to help you find something in a file that we can't see?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No,I don't mean that. I tried grep,  but couldn't concatenate both. so, i asked a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk '/random/{print x;print;next}{x=$0};/fail|pass/' A.log

It will print only previous line of "random" search and also words "fail|pass" from same file

Comment: Working Perfect. Thanks @Sneha.N

Comment: Great @Eashwar Gadanchi